# QPython3 permission error - subprocess module on android

Tags: android, python, subprocess, qpython, qpython3

I want to run some apps on android with QPython3. So I tried but got permission error.

```
#-*-coding:utf8;-*-
#qpy:3
#qpy:console

import subprocess
yt = subprocess.Popen('/system/app/YouTube/YouTube.apk')
yt.wait()
print("done")
```

The result is following : 
(snip)
"..../subprocess.py" line 1356, in _execute_child
OSError : [Errno 13] Permissio denied

Help me please...

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you cannot execute an `.apk` directly. You would use `subprocess` to run Unix commands like `ls` or other "real" ELF executables.

Comment: I am a beginner of programming. So, unfortunately I'dont know what you mean at all. Eventhough I feel shamed, could you let me know the concrete method step by step? I would appreciae you.

Comment: Is there no way to run '.apk' with Qpython3? OTL

Comment: `subprocess` runs executables. Apps aren't simply executables. If you're trying to launch an app, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12737150/launch-android-app-from-sl4a-script.