# Get list of all apps with QPython / sl4a

Tags: android, sl4a, qpython, qpython3

Does anyone know how I can get a list of packages from all apps installed on Android using Qpython?

My goal is to list all apps and be able to run, using `getLaunchableApplications()` and the "launch" function until I could open some, but it does not work for everyone. I made tests and if I get the name of the packages I should be able to open any app with `startActivity()`.

Answer (score 1):

here is a code to print out all launchable apps using the `androidhelper` module

```
import androidhelper
droid=androidhelper.Android()
launchable_app=droid.getLaunchableApplications()
print(launchable_app)
```

you can use `pprint()` instead of `print()` to get a readable format

Comment: Great! I didn't see it before! Here is the documentation: [ApplicationManagerFacade](http://www.mithril.com.au/android/doc/ApplicationManagerFacade.html).

Comment: `getLaunchableApplications().result` returns a dictionary of `u"AppName":u"ClassName"` pair, then you can launch by calling `launch(u"ClassName")`! It's definitely better than using `subprocess`.

Answer (score 0):

There's an executable `pm`(package manager) inside Android, use `pm list packages` to list installed packages. If you want to automate the query progress, `subprocess.check_output(["pm","list","packages"])` may be a good way.

As for your second question--"launch the app", it has been answered here: [Launch android app from SL4A script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12737150/launch-android-app-from-sl4a-script)

Comment: I don't know why people downvote this question, if there are some problems in this question, I think people who downvote should at least comment to explain why they downvote since downvote itself doesn't help, right?

Comment: I completely agree. I have been a victim of illogical voting situations as well.
There should be one comment compulsory for a vote down!
Just to keep it anonymous is not reason enough to allow Stack Overflow users to commit a hate-crime and get away with it without a question or a review.. Meta Community, please please read this ASAP.

thanks!